# Glimpse - ASP.NET MVC4 & EF5 in a n-layer application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, glimpse

I have created a n-layer ASP.NET MVC4 application. I am using Entity Framework 5.0. The entity framework layer is separate from ASP.NET MVC4 App layer.

I have also installed `Glimpse.MVC4` and `Glimpse.EF5` via Nuget. All my dependencies for glimpse are up-to-date.

All my tabs work except SQL tab. Should I install glimpse in the Entity framework layer too? Or a configuration setting to enable SQL tab?

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: In which of your projects have you installed which Glimpse packages?

Comment: In my ASP.NET MVC project, I have installed Glimpse.ASPNet, Glimpse.MVC4. In my Entity Framework project(which is a class library project) I have installed Glimpse.EF5. @nikmd23

Comment: I also tried installing Glimpse.EF5 in ASP.NET MVC project, with no luck.

Comment: @nikmd23 thanks to Glimpse's plugin architecture, I have written my own logger now. :-).

Comment: Glimpse packages only need to be installed in the web project. After you do an install, be sure to restart the web server.

Comment: @nikmd23 I restarted the whole operating system. I still see 0 Db queries and 0s to complete them. :-(

Comment: Do you manage the connection manually, or does Entity Framework handle that for you?

Comment: I have same issue, with latest nuget packages installed in the web project, I do not see anything. I do manage the connection string manually as it is encrypted in quite different way.  How do i get glimpse working in this scenario? thx